# How to create a box that holds a paragraph of text in HTML5

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I've been trying to create a box that contains a paragraph of text, I've tried looking online, but I am still having a hard time creating one.

Here is the informations from the band.css style sheet for the paragraph box :

```css
div {
   width: 80%;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 5px solid gray;
   margin: 0;
}
```

And here is the code in the program for the paragraph I want to enclose in a box :

```html
<p style="text-align: center">
    Manfred Mann's Earth Band is an English rock band founded by Manfred Mann, a musician from South Africa. 
    <br> They are known for doing covers of Bruce Springsteen songs.
</p>
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: You need to add a div parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your p tag inside of the div container, and create a class or id to identify the div for styling.

```
<div class="text-box">
 <p style="text-align: center">Manfred Mann's Earth Band is an English rock band founded by Manfred Mann, a musician from South Africa. 
 <br> They are known for doing covers of Bruce Springsteen songs.
 </p>
</div>


div.text-box {
 width: 80%;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 5px solid gray;
 margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/efLbp1y7/1/

Comment: I tried doing that, but no box appeared.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working?

Comment: Here's the code for the program:
<div class="text-box">
 <p style="text-align: center">
 Manfred Mann's Earth Band is an English rock band founded by Manfred Mann, a musician from South Africa. 
 <br> They are known for doing covers of Bruce Springsteen songs.
 </p>
</div>
Here's the code from the css:
div.text-box {
   width: 80%;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 5px solid gray;
   margin: 0;
}

Comment: I'm trying to see a working example of what isn't working. Can you psot code to a site like jsfiddle.net or a similar site?

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/xwvf5ht2/

Comment: It's not working because you put HTML and CSS in the Javascript box. It all works when you put the proper code in their respective boxes. See my fiddle for reference at https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/efLbp1y7/1/